# Is there anyway to remove an onTouchListener from a view object?

Tags: android, webview, touch, listener

I have an on touch listener for a webview, but it has a bad effect on the functionality of the webview, so I am wondering if there is anyway to removed the on touch listener after the initial interaction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So in you activity you would set your overridden onTouchListener:

```
            mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.setOnTouchListener(mWebView.mOnTouchListener);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And you would have to make a new class, extending WebView. And within it you would define an OnTouchListener.

```
    public final OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Setting the ontouchlistener to null doesn't reset it to the default definition. You still have to provide an actual listener.

Comment: pretty cool idea, but can you elaborate on how the new class interacts with `mWebView` ?  How does mWebView get to mOnTouchListener? thanks!

Comment: mWebView is not a standard Android Webview control. Instead, it is a custom control you created, which is simply a new class that inherits from WebView.

Comment: BTW, if you are extending a `View` such as `WebView`, you don't need to implement a touch listener.  View has a built-in method that you implement instead: `boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) { ... }`.  The advantage of creating a touch listener is that you can do it in **some other class**, such as a Fragment or Activity, that you are already defining. So you don't have to create another new class.

Comment: .. But more importantly for the original question, if you **do** subclass `WebView`, in your `onTouchEvent` you will pass the event on to original class by calling `base.onTouchEvent(event)` whenever you *don't* handle the event yourself. "Removing" your problematic touch stuff simply means you set some flag that you test to decide whether to use your custom code.  Something like `boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  if (doMyCustomCode) { .. code here ..;  return true; } else return base.onTouchEvent(event);  }`

Comment: .. Or better:  `boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  boolean handled = false;  if (doMycustomCode) { .. code here that sets handled=true after doing whatever, if it is an event that you respond to .. }  if (handled) return true; else return base.onTouchEvent(event); }`

Answer (score 46):

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Comment: Does that remove the on touch listener so that the functionality will return to normal, or does it just set the listener to null meaning that the webview won't do anything when it is touched?

Comment: thanks for the help, but I've just tested it and I'm still having the same functionality issues. (For example, double tap to zoom doesn't work)

Comment: how about make custom onTouchListener and return false ??

Comment: Then the webview still thinks it has an onTouchListener and won't do it's default functionality.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for help online and got to this post.
When I did

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

my `myView` stopped responding to the `onTouch`.